# rgb not working on keyboard GS66 STEALTH SERIES

Tags: kernel, keyboard, msi, keyboard-backlight, 22.04

I can't get the rgb to work on my keyboard and tried with msiklm and with msi-keyboard and not find my keyboard in ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-25-generic

Will they have any solution?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Comment: I have the same issue on MSI GS66 Stealth 11UE with Ubuntu 22.04 the RGB backlights are not working. Did you found a solution ?